# Install git repository as library in node. When using inside node18-alpine docker

Tags: node.js, git, docker, npm

I'm trying to get node working from inside a docker (based on node18-alpine). However whenever I try to add a library with a git repository this is the error i am given:

npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects clone -b production 
/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneKFjcID --recurse-submodules
npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneKFjcID': Permission denied

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-08-29T14_17_35_621Z-debug-0.log

(the log file has no different errors).

I've noticed that npm in alpine docker runs as `node` whereas the main user is `root` so I changed the ownership of `/root/.npm` to node. I've also tried changing the permissions to "777" to just allow everything (it's inside a docker anyways, recursive through `chmod 777 -R /root/.npm/_cacache`).

So when I test the permissions `ls -ld /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp` The result is

```
drwxrwxrwx    1 node     node          4096 Aug 29 14:17 /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp
```

Yet the same error occurs, what can be the problem? As far as I can see everything is setup correctly and node should have permission to do whatever it wants in the directory?

Comment: Docker has the ability to do arbitrary UID mapping: are you sure that the user `node` inside the docker setup is the same user as the user `node` outside the docker setup? Make sure whoever `node` is inside the docker image has the required permissions.

Comment: @torek: I've been running those commands from within the docker shell.

Comment: OK, that should help for sure. It's curious that there would be any permission denied issues at this point...